# Cannot remove HTML Class with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with my code and I am really struggling with understanding why it is not working. I put my code on JSFiddle so you can test it (https://jsfiddle.net/veka33/3rv0wft7/21/). With my code I start an animation when a buttion is clicked. After the animation is run the div is fully shown when I click on it. When the div is expanded I want to change the position of the div so I cannot see it fully. I wanted to do that with removing the class ".scoreExpand" by clicking the exit button. However, I cannot remove this class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clickMe").click(function() {
    $(".score").addClass("showScore");
  });
  $(".score").click(function() {
    $(".score").removeClass("showScore");
    $(".score").addClass("scoreExpand");
    $("#exitScore").css("visibility", "visible");
  });
  $("#exitScore").click(function() {
    $(".scoreExpand").removeClass("scoreExpand");
  });

});
```

```css
.score {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  right: -250px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 2em;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  border-color: yellow;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
}

.showScore {
  animation: showScoreboard 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  right: -250px;
}

.scoreExpand {
  animation: fixScoreboard 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  right: 50px;
}

#flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 30px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@keyframes showScoreboard {
  50% {
    right: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    right: -150px;
  }
}

@keyframes fixScoreboard {
  0% {
    right: -150px;
  }
  50% {
    right: -50px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 50px;
  }
}

#exitScore {
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  top: 35px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: yellow;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div>
  <button id="clickMe">Clicke Me!</button>
</div>
<div class="score">
  <div id="flexContainer">
    <i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size: 30px; color: yellow;"></i>
    <p style="padding-right: 50px; font-size: 20px; vertical-align: top; line-height: 0px;" id="scoreDisplay">Score: </p>
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-times-circle" id="exitScore"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. fixed click event target from `.score` to `#flexContainer` which is making a conflict with click event of child element `#exitScore`
2. added shirnking animation, mapping class and add/remove the class on corresponding situation.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $(".score").addClass("showScore");
  });
  $("#flexContainer").click(function(){
     $(".score").removeClass("showScore");
     $(".score").removeClass("scoreShrink");
     $(".score").addClass("scoreExpand");
     $("#exitScore").css("visibility","visible");
  });
    
  $("#exitScore").click(function(){
     $(".score").removeClass("scoreExpand");
     $(".score").addClass("scoreShrink");
  });
    
});
```

```css
.score {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: -250px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 2em;
    color: white;
    background-color: grey;
    border-color: yellow;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
}

.showScore {
    animation: showScoreboard 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    right: -250px;
}

.scoreExpand {
    animation: fixScoreboard 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    right: 50px;
}

.scoreShrink {
    animation: unfixScoreboard 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    right: -150px;
}

#flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 30px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

@keyframes showScoreboard {
    50% {
        right: 50px;
    }
    100% {
        right: -150px;
    }
}

@keyframes fixScoreboard {
    0% {
        right: -150px;
    }
    50% {
        right: -50px;
    }
    100% {
        right: 50px;
    }
}

@keyframes unfixScoreboard {
    0% {
        right: 50px;
    }
    50% {
        right: -50px;
    }
    100% {
        right: -150px;
    }
}

#exitScore {
    position: absolute;
    left: 220px;
    top: 35px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: yellow;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype hmlt>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
         <div>
         <button id="clickMe">
         Clicke Me!
         </button>
         </div>
         <div class="score">
            <div id="flexContainer">
                <i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size: 30px; color: yellow;"></i>
                <p style="padding-right: 50px; font-size: 20px; vertical-align: top; line-height: 0px;" id="scoreDisplay">Score: </p>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle" id="exitScore"></i>
        </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This make sense to me and also nice that you implemented a shrink class, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have added two listeners who do opposite things on the same object. Just change the element that holds the listener ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $(".score").addClass("showScore");
  });
  $("#flexContainer").click(function(){
     $(".score").removeClass("showScore");
     $(".score").addClass("scoreExpand");
     $("#exitScore").css("visibility","visible");
  });
    
  $("#exitScore").click(function(){
     $(".scoreExpand").removeClass("scoreExpand");
  });
    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the whole `.score` has the listener attached, and `#exitScore` is inside that div, so whenever you click it both handlers are called.

It works if you use the `#flexContainer` instead:

```
$("#flexContainer").click(function() {
  $(".score").removeClass("showScore");
  $(".score").addClass("scoreExpand");
  $("#exitScore").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand that!